# Error in my PDO execute function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following query:

```
SELECT case when card_type='A'  then name else  CONCAT_WS(' ',firstname,lastname)  end 
                     as cname ,cardid,card_type,isDeck,userid_from,status,cards.gibid,message ,userid_to,description,tagline,gibs.preview_thumb
                    ,case when  userid_from=userid_to then 'my card ' else 'other 'end as owner 
            FROM cards LEFT JOIN gibs ON gibs.gibid=cards.gibid
                left join users on users.userid=cards.userid_from
            WHERE userid_to=? and cards.deleted='N'  and (case when card_type='A'  then name else  CONCAT_WS(' ',firstname,lastname)  end)  like '%?%'
            order by status,card_type desc,owner,cname,isDeck desc
```

and array passed in execute function is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => rahul
)
```

it is giving me error ..

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /var/www/ryapi/Db.php on line 176

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'Database error [HY093]: , driver error code is ' in /var/www/ryapi/Db.php:179
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/ryapi/Db.php(93): Db::_query('SELECT case whe...', Array)
#1 /var/www/ryapi/card.php(152): Db::getResult('SELECT case whe...', Array)
#2 /var/www/ryapi/index.php(103): Card->getcardlist('1', '', 'rahul')
#3 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/ryapi/Db.php on line 179
```

why this error is coming please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CONCAT_WS(' ',firstname,lastname)  end)  like '%?%'
```

Here, '%?%' is not a pdo param.
You should make it:

```
CONCAT_WS(' ',firstname,lastname)  end)  like ?
```

Then bind:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => '%rahul%'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely your problem:

```
CONCAT_WS(' ',firstname,lastname)  end)  like '%?%'
```

Binding parameters does not work that way, you need to change it to

```
CONCAT_WS(' ',firstname,lastname)  end)  like ?
```

and extend the value you're passing in with the wildcards.

Comment: but by doing this not returning any result

Comment: @Rahul Mehta: Re-read my last sentence or read the answer of pinusnegra.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple error that can be fixed in your PHP. You have not included the PHP, so we can't tell.

You need to adjust the number of ? symbols in your pdo->prepare statement.